# SQL Service Broker Vs Windows Workflow Foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, service-broker

Apologies if this is a broad question...just wanted to if any has an idea with regards the comparison of SQL Service Broker Vs Windows Workflow Foundation for Workflow development.

R,

Answer (score 1):

These are two different technologies to solve different problems. One deals with messaging between multiple applications, and the other deals with modeling of business processes.

**SQL Service Broker** is a messaging paradigm that is provided in SQL Server between two or more applications. It provides the ability to have multiple applications communicate with each other by placing messages on queues, and SQL Server would take care of delivering messages to other applications asynchronously.

**Windows Workflow Foundation** provides the ability to define business processes in either a flow-chart or state-machine fashion.